# Vaadin - Input password field fails login when setting password

Tags: selenium, vaadin

I'm new to vaadin-testbench and I'm trying to automate a login into a website but when I set user and password using vaadin test it says that the credentials are wrong but if I copy the credentials used in the test and paste them manually into the login form I can log in without any problem. Any idea why this can be happening?

This is my login function

```
public void login(String username, String password){

    $("input").id("username").setProperty("value",username);
    $("input").id("password").setProperty("value",password);
    $("div").id("loginBtn").click();

}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
login.login("test@test.com", "Testvaadin123");
```

Any ideas why can this be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you're using TestBench incorrectly. Instead of `$("input").id("username").setProperty("value",username)` you should use `$(TextFieldElement.class).id("username").setValue(username);`, which if we look at the [sources](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/testbench-api/src/main/java/com/vaadin/testbench/elements/AbstractTextFieldElement.java#L42) does the following:

```
/**
 * Set value of the field element.
 *
 * @param chars
 *            new value of the field
 */
public void setValue(CharSequence chars) throws ReadOnlyException {
    if (isReadOnly()) {
        throw new ReadOnlyException();
    }
    clearElementClientSide(this);
    focus();
    sendKeys(chars);
    sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

Suppose you have a form like:

```
public class LoginComponent extends FormLayout {

    public LoginComponent() {
        TextField userField = new TextField("Username", "defaultUser");
        userField.setId("username");

        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField("Password", "defaultPwd");
        passwordField.setId("password");

        // simulate a login action by displaying a notification
        Button loginButton = new Button("Login", event -> Notification
            .show("Logging in [" + userField.getValue() + "] with [" + passwordField.getValue() + "]", Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        loginButton.setId("login");

        addComponents(userField, passwordField, loginButton);
    }
}
```

You can write the test like:

```
public class LoginComponentTest extends TestBenchTestCase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<PATH TO DRIVER>");
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        getDriver().get("http://localhost:8080/");
    }

        @Test
    public void shouldLogin() throws Exception {
        // get username field and set value
        $(TextFieldElement.class).id("username").setValue("myUser");

        // get password field and set value
        $(PasswordFieldElement.class).id("password").setValue("myPwd");

        // get login button and click
        $(ButtonElement.class).id("login").click();

        // wait until notification visible or 5 secs have passed
        waitUntil(webDriver -> isElementPresent(NotificationElement.class), 5);

        // check that login was successful
        ElementQuery<NotificationElement> elementQuery = $(NotificationElement.class);
        assertThat(elementQuery.first().getCaption(), is("Logging in [myUser] with [myPwd]"));
    }
}
```

And this is how your app will look like:

[image: result]